# how can I learn android

Tags: android

I am new in making android applications... if you have any good tutorial for learning android (either it is book or video) then plz give me the links.... so that it is helpfull to me...

Comment: Buy a book, look at the SDK help/samples, google for tutorials. There are thousands of pages out there.

Answer (score 4):

1) Watch the videos at developer.android.com.

2) Ask beginner questions at stackoverflow.com

3) Go through the example projects at developer.android.com

4) Go to youtube.com and search for android bootcamp(excellent beginner videos!)

For anything else you want to do use google and the developer.android.com site as reference. I have skimmed through 5-10 android books and they all seemed like they were rushed to be published.  The authors are always leaving out some major points. However it might not hurt to read the first couple chapters in a few books if you are a complete newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Its best to start reading up about Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).

You can find useful Android tutorials [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial). They are pretty good!

You can also see some sample code of projects Android have done [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample), which can help understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need as a beginner is at developer.android.com.  Once you start dealing with somewhat advanced projects, stackoverflow and the Android Google group become your friend.